# Changing color of an Image in Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define obamicon
  (lambda (clr2)
  (image-map (lambda (clr1) (image-ref clr1 (+ (color-ref clr1 'red)(color-ref clr1 'green)
                                          (color-ref clr1 'blue))))

(cond
      [(<= clr2 181) (color-set! clr2 [0 51 76])]
      [(and (>= clr2 182) (<= clr2 363)) (color-set! clr2 [217 26 33])]
      [(and (>= clr2 364) (<= clr2 545)) (color-set! clr2 [112 150 158])]
      [(and (>= clr2 546) (<= clr2 765)) (color-set! clr2 [252 227 166])]))))
```

I'm making a program that changes an image to emulate the Obama campaign posters. The image-map suppose to take each pixel and add them to get a sum and that sum is checked in the cond statement to see what color is suppose to replace it. As of now, I get

```
Exception in <=: #[color 0 0 0] is not a real number or clr1 is not bound.
```

Any ideas to what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Dwayne, is that all one error you get or are those two different errors in different circumstances?  If it's the latter case, which inputs provide the first error and which the second?

Answer (score 0):

That's not your compiler complaining about a syntax error, that's the **image-map** function (or, rather, a function that it calls) complaining about a parameter that has been passed to it.

I'm not familiar with the **image-map** function (is it a standard library function or one you wrote?)  but I think there are structural errors in your code.  You are calling **image-map** with two parameters - one is an function, the other is the output of the **cond** statement.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant to do or if it is then the **cond** statement is returning an undefined value .  I think that **image-map** is receiving nothing useful in its second parameter and is then calling your anonymous function with no value to pass to it.  Your anonymous function then complains.

So sort out your code structure.  What is supposed to be in the second parameter to image-map?  Work out how to put it there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the statements which look like `(<= clr2 181)`, because colors cannot be compared to numbers. Thus, the `<=` function is complaining that you didn't pass it two numbers, you passed it a color and a number.

Comment: How would you go about adding all the colors of a pixel and testing it to see what range you're in?

Comment: Break your problem into smaller pieces.  Your question has two parts.  Attack the first part.  How would you add all the colors of a pixel?  You're doing it in the code already, right?  Can you make that a helper function?  Call it "color-intensity" or something like that, and have it take in a pixel and return the sum of all its components.  That way, you can more easily do things, such as testing the intensity of a color, by having the vocabulary to say things like *(< (color-intensity a-pixel) 181)*.